# Printing document on windows7 from printer which is connected to Ubuntu (via RDP on Ubuntu)

Tags: printing, windows-7, rdp

I have a printer on Ubuntu. I want to print a document on Windows7 via RDP on Ubuntu.
ı want to connect Windows7 via RDP on Ubuntu. ı will choose a document there. The document will be printed from my printer which connects on Ubuntu. 
How can i solve this problem?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please **clarify** your question. To which computer is the printer physically connected? It is shared through what protocol? Perhaps Samba, and not RDP? What is your problem **exactly**? You can't access your printer from Windows? Ubuntu doesn't see it? You'll get alot more answers if your question and problem are **clearly explained**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wanting to support a local printer connected to their Linux system via RDP (Remote Desktop) connecting to a Windows server, here is a quick how-to.
First look up the Printer Name on your Linux box, it is best if it is a single word and under 20 characters. You can typically find this by opening a document, selecting Print and it should be the name in the drop down.

Next you will have a script that call rdesktop like so:
    rdesktop -r printer:="WINDOWS DRIVER NAME AS IT APPEARS IN ADD PRINTER" 
    Run the rdesktop script and login
    Go to Printers and Faxes
    Right-click on the Printer that matches your Linux printer's name and choose Properties
    Print a test page!

[source](http://cpradio.org/personal/local-printer-support-via-rdp-remote-desktop/)